# python tkinter listbox performance with other tk/ttk widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkwidgets

I tried to isolate the problem as best as i could.

Lets assume that there are 3 tk/ttk widgets.
Why doesn't the tk_spinbox unselect the selected listbox entry and why does the ttk_spinbox?
I dont want to unselect the items whenever the ttk_spinbox is pressed. Is there an workaround in order to get an equal behaviour for ttk_spinbox and tk_spinbox?

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

masterframe = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(masterframe, height=5, selectmode='multiple')
listbox.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
listbox.insert(tk.END, 'blubb_1')
listbox.insert(tk.END, 'blubb_2')

tk_spinbox = tk.Spinbox(masterframe,from_=10, to=20, increment=2)
tk_spinbox.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

ttk_spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(masterframe,from_=10, to=20, increment=2)
ttk_spinbox.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

masterframe.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "why" is simply, that's how they are designed to work. When you interact with a ttk spinbox, the spinbox value is automatically selected. This doesn't happen for the tk spinbox. By default only one thing can have the selection at a time, so the listbox loses the selection when the spinbox gains the selection.

If you don't want to have the listbox lose the selection you can set the `exportselection` option to False on the listbox and/or the ttk spinbox.

Comment: Thank you very much. The exportselection=False solves the problem. I didn't know that the widgets somehow interact on a regular basis.